# Is my analysis of this current mirror correct?

Tags: current-source

\$I_{ref} = I_1 = 1 mA \$.

For NMOS, \$V_{T_n} = 1 V\$, \$K_n = 50 \mu A/V^2 \$, \$ \lambda_n = 0\$.

For PMOS, \$V_{T_p} = -1 V\$, \$K_p = 25 \mu A/V^2 \$, \$ \lambda_p = 0\$.

[image]

The following is my analysis.

$$I_{D1} = \frac{1}{2} \times 25 \mu \:\left[\frac{A}{V^2}\right] \times 
\frac{50}{10} \times (15 \:[V] - V_{G1} -1\: [V])^2 = 1 mA$$

$$\Rightarrow V_{G1} = 10 V$$

$$I_{D2} = \frac{1}{2} \times 50 \mu \:\left[\frac{A}{V^2}\right]  \times \frac{25}{10} \times (V_{G2} - 1\: [V])^2 = 1 mA$$

$$\Rightarrow V_{G2} = 5 V$$

$$\frac{V_{G1} - V_{G2}} {R} = 1 mA$$
$$\Rightarrow R = 5 k \Omega$$

Comment: Can you show how you calculated your answer? (I haven't a clue!)

Comment: @Transistor Take a look at my analysis

Comment: @G36 Could you please take a look if you have time?

Comment: Again, I haven't a clue, but what is \$V\$ in the \$V^2\$ in the first equation? Why have you a `-1` in there when the gate is tied to drain / top of \$R\$?

Comment: Yes, your calculations are correct. Good job.

Comment: @Transistor -1 is \$V_T\$ Threshold voltage. \$K = C_{ox} \mu \$Please take a look at modified answer